# social media slang identifier

Tags: java, spring

I am doing a project on social media slang identifier.I have to identify abbreviations from different comments.But the problem is that, suppose in a particular comment it's written GM (means Good Morning) and at the same time in some other comment it's written again GM (means General Manager).

So I need to differentiate between these two, although it shows same in both case (i.e. GM). 

I am really confused in this problem.I am not getting any idea for this.

Can any one help me to overcome from this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem. You need some semantic algorithm to make this distinction.
You cannot infer the meaning just from the syntax or just from the textual representation.

Google "disambiguation natural language processing". You will see lots of resources.
This is just to give you a hint. As said the problem is broad and complex.

Comment: the actual terms for searching are useful. +1

Comment: Can you please give me some more clear idea

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very complex issue.
From my understanding of it you would need a quite large dictionary of these abbreviations and also, the `lexical field` (a.k.a. [semantic field)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_field) in which they are used.

In order to detect the `lexical field` you could also group the speakers into "work related" or "colleagues from university" or "drinking buddies", and maybe have a standard for these groups, so that data from other users is also used. In order to understand this, maybe you can understand a sort of synonym of slang, which is [argot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot).

So for instance, if someone says "the GM's feedback was actually pretty good" not only do you understand that it is a usual noun but feedback is also from the "business" `lexical field`.

An actual time frame, and data you'd work with would be useful, and I will edit this answer accordingly.